# Interface member with multiple arguments

Tags: f#

How can I declare interface member with two arguments? Something like:

```
type IService = 
   abstract myMember: (a:int) (b:string) -> result
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a function with two arguments:

```
type IService = 
   abstract member myMember: int -> string -> string
```

Alternatively, you could use a tuple:

```
type IService = 
   abstract member myMember: int * string -> string
```

The reason the syntax is `int -> string -> string` (where an arrow denotes the return of a function) is because functions with multiple parameters in F# can be partially applied by default.

It's also important to note that if you're writing a library that you intend to consume from other .net languages, you should use the tuple form.

Comment: Important note: if you plan on consuming this interface from other .NET languages, such as C# or VB.NET, you should use the tuple form.